# Efficient way to add rows to dataframe while being able to add column names

Tags: r

I have a loop where in each iteration I generate a named numeric vector and add the contents to a dataframe. This dataframe has one row for each vector, and each column is a unique word. As different vectors might contain different words, with each newly added row a column might be added which is NA for the other rows.

However, this is a very slow process as the dataframe grows bigger, I think because the data frame is being copied everytime a new row is added. My current approach is therefore not feasible to deploy to a big dataset (on my laptop, ~650 rows of a few thousand unique words already takes hours)

I've found some suggested solutions such as preallocating memory, but this is not an option for me as I don't know the number of unique words (columns) beforehand. Also, using a data.table is supposed to be faster but then checking for the column is hard and I need a dataframe for later use.

This is my approach right now:

```
# example vectors
named_num1 = c(alpha = 1, beta = 4, gamma =2) 
named_num2 = c(alpha = 5, pi = 2, gamma = 18) 
named_num3 = c(beta = 10, omega = 12, alpha = 2)
list_of_nums = list(named_num1,named_num2,named_num3)

df = data.frame()

# add vectors to dataframe
for (num in list_of_nums){
  temp_df = data.frame(as.list(num))
  df = dplyr::bind_rows(df, temp_df)
}

df[is.na(df)] = 0
```

I'm kind of lost on how to improve on this. Do you have an approach that works faster while still being able to add the columns? Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: You can use the deprecated.function `rbind_list` from `dplyr`, which - to my surprise - works as opposed to `bind_rows`. So try `rbind_list(list_of_nums)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works, but is not necessarily quicker. I think the problem is that it writes the whole df to another df at the line ```df = dplyr::bind_rows(df, temp_df)``` so I think I'm searching for an alternative for that

Comment: Is it possible to first generate all vectors and then use only a single `bind_rows()`? This would speed up your code significantly

Comment: @Robbert I think you got me wrong. Store the vectors in a list just like you did in your question and then only call `rbind_list(list_of_nums)` instead of your whole loop. See my answer for a benchmark.

Comment: You're right, I didn't understand correctly. @Julian_Hn, I could, but then I'd need to store these vectors in some kind of structure too and I'll have the same problem right?

Comment: No. Because the `bind_rows()` is what makes your code so slow. If you do this each time you initalize a new `tibble` in each iteration which is a lot slower than just initializing vectors in a loop beforehand.

Comment: Alright, I'll take that approach then. Thanks a bunch for your help both :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use deprecated `rbind_list` from `dplyr`

```
rbind_list(list_of_nums)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  alpha  beta gamma    pi omega
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     4     2    NA    NA
#2     5    NA    18     2    NA
#3     2    10    NA    NA    12
#warning:
#'rbind_list' is deprecated.
#Use 'bind_rows()' instead.
#See help("Deprecated")
```

**benchmark**

```
l <- rep(list_of_nums, 10000)

library(microbenchmark)
b <- microbenchmark(
  markus = rbind_list(l),
  OP = OP(l), 
  Julian_Hn = bind_rows(!!!l),
  times = 10L
)

autoplot(b)
```

[image]

```
b
#Unit: milliseconds
#      expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval cld
#    markus   108.43026   108.98696   119.86560   122.87064   128.76507   134.64753    10  a 
#        OP 33415.89685 33647.62856 34314.40213 34058.06817 34695.69121 36231.96304    10   b
# Julian_Hn    27.36839    27.77864    30.83439    28.44502    29.68894    42.87212    10  a
```

---

Where `OP` is given by

```
OP <- function(x) {
  df = data.frame()

  for (num in x) {
    temp_df = data.frame(as.list(num))
    df = dplyr::bind_rows(df, temp_df)
  }
  df
}
```

Comment: To avoid the usage of the deprecated `rbind_list` we could use the now idiomatic `bind_rows(!!!l)` to explicitly splice the list before binding together. This is even faster for me (by a factor of roughly 3 according to microbenchmark).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. However, if I use your solution I would need to generate my vectors before and store them in a structure too and I'll have the same problem again right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Julian_Hn Thanks for the comment! Didn't know about this syntax. Updated the benchmark.

Comment: @Robbert I don't think so. Generate a list of appropriate length and fill in your vectors, then call `bind_rows` as suggested by Julian. If you have trouble doing this consider to ask a new question where you show how these vectors are created.